# Update only calls a single time in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to test this health bar for a game I'm making in Unity.

However, when I run the game the script only returns then number 1 once. I can wait as long as I like and when I hit 'e' it sends me 3 then 2 in the console. Is the update function not working at all or am I just dumb?

The video I watched that walked me through this pretty much had the same exact thing as me except Unity wouldn't let me make the UpdateSan private for some reason.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

   

 public class sanity : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [SerializeField]private float Max;
        [SerializeField]private float Father;
        [SerializeField]private float Daughter;
        [SerializeField]private Image FatherI;
        [SerializeField]private Image DaughterI;
        [SerializeField]private int d;

        private void Update()
        {
            Debug.Log("1");
            if (Input.GetKeyDown("e"))
            {
                Father -= d;
                UpdateSan();
                Debug.Log("2");
            }

            void UpdateSan()
            {
                FatherI.fillAmount = Father / Max;
                Debug.Log("3");
            }
        }
    }
```

If anyone could help that would be great.

Comment: Why do you nest the `UpdateScan` under the `Update` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure it is only printing once, or is Unity collapsing all of the prints into a stack? Whenever there is a printout and the print is exactly the same, Unity will usually just increase a counter for that specific printout.

As for your code, why do you have your function `UpdateSan` inside of `Update`? I would move it outside of the function and call it instead of placing it within the other function.

Here is an example of what I mean. When you toggle the `Collapse` button on/off it will stack the printouts. When you toggle the button, do you still only get one print?

[image: Example]

Comment: thank you, I did have collapse on. and as for the UpdateSan function being in the Update that was a mistake that I took out.

Answer (score 0):

You use `Input.GetKeyDown()` this method returns TRUE only one time per click on button.

If You need TRUE in every frame while you press button (<kbd>e</kbd> in your case), you must use `Input.GetKey()`